# Dependency Tree Error while installing craco-less

Tags: reactjs, npm-install

I am new to React/Node.js and trying out the Ant Framework with React.

While installing craco-less [`npm install craco-less`], I am getting following error:

```
While resolving: mytestproject@0.1.0
Found: react-scripts@4.0.0
node_modules/react-scripts
  react-scripts@"4.0.0" from the root project
  peer react-scripts@"*" from @craco/craco@5.8.0
  node_modules/@craco/craco
    @craco/craco@"^5.8.0" from the root project
    peer @craco/craco@"^5.5.0" from craco-less@1.17.0
    node_modules/craco-less
      craco-less@"*" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer react-scripts@"^3.3.0" from craco-less@1.17.0
node_modules/craco-less
  craco-less@"*" from the root project
```

I am not sure what to do. Any help here?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i react-scripts@latest
```

installing updates helped for me